# Why is passing function argument to React.useState and the return function will return stale value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Give the codes below

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = useState(0);

  const inc1 = () => {
    console.log("debug inc:", count1);
    setCount1((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const inc2 = () => {
    console.log("debug inc2:", count2);
    setCount2(count2 + 1);
  };

  const [processInc1] = useState(() => {
    console.log("debug longProcessBeforeInc:", count1);
    // Run some long process here
    return inc1;
  });

  const [processInc2] = useState(() => {
    console.log("debug longProcessBeforeInc:", count2);
    // Run some long process here
    return inc2;
  });

  console.log("debug render:", count1, count2);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>
        {count1} - {count2}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={inc1}>Inc 1</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={inc2}>Inc 2</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={processInc1}>Long Inc 1</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={processInc2}>Long Inc 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`inc1`, `inc2`, `processInc1` all works as expected where you increase value by 1 and it renders correctly.

So with `inc1`, `inc2` the main difference is `setCount1((prev) => prev + 1);` and `setCount2(count2 + 1);`, and `processInc1`, `processInc2` basically return `inc1` and `inc2` respectively via useState first time the component renders.

I understand from here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function that it has something to do with closure but given the example above I fail to wrap my head around why `inc2`, and `processInc1` works but not `processInc2`?

Here is the link to the `codesandbox` for the above
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-morse-37xyoy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `processInc2` is an instance of the `inc2` function as it was at the first render, so the `count2` that function is using is also as it was at the first render, that is 0. Similarly `processInc1` is an instance of the `inc1` function, but the difference is that `inc1` always uses the _current_ state of `count1`.

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you are abusing the `useState` lazy initialisation, for you to eventually just return `incN`. Very similar behaviour could also be achieved with a combination of `useEffect` and `useCallback`. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/0583c84c9b0c110fc490bec25a997bc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very important detail here is that `inc1` and `inc2` are re-defined each time the `App` component renders.

```
function App() {
  // ...

  const inc1 = () => {
    console.log("debug inc:", count1);
    setCount1((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  // ...
}
```

You then store those 2 functions inside a state, that does never change.

```js
const [processInc1] = useState(() => {
  console.log("debug longProcessBeforeInc:", count1);
  // Run some long process here
  return inc1;
});
```

This will result in `processInc1` and `processInc2` that point to the very first definition of `inc1` and `inc2` (created on the first render).

The reason `count1` and `count2` never update in this first version of the function is because the variable(s) are never re-assigned. This is by design.

The only reason `count1` and `count2` change in a future render is because `useState()` will return the new value. After you receive this new value `inc1` and `inc2` are re-defined.

`processInc1` and `processInc2` are then pulled out of a React state that holds the first definition of `inc1` and `inc2`, so usage of `count1` and `count2` inside those functions will refer to the first value of `count1` and `count2`.

When you do `setCount2(count2 + 1)` inside `inc2` and call it via `processInc2` the value of `count2` is still `0` and will never change. This is because `processInc2` refers to the very first definition of `inc2`, and not the current definition.

`setCount1((prev) => prev + 1)` works due to the different function signature. Where `inc2` passes a static value (`0 + 1`) to the setter, `inc1` passes a transformation (as a callback). When you pass a function to `setCount1` React will call that function with the current state as the sole argument. The return value is then used as the new state. So although `processInc1` still uses the very first definition of `inc1`. It will always be relevant, since it describes the transformation that must be made rather than the value that must be set.

Do note that `console.log("debug inc:", count1);` will keep logging `0` when called via `processInc1` for the above reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path. As you were saying, this problem is actually caused by the use of the closure. So let's start by showing you a nice definition of closure:

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

This means that when you return the closure *inc2* in the useState, you are also creating a copy of the variables that are used at that particular time (i.e. initial rendering) by that lexical environment (this includes the count2 value). This is why ***processInc2*** will keep having the same old count2 value.

At the same time ***processInc1*** function will work correctly because, by using a callback in the useState, you are always getting the current value of the count1 state.

Lastly, ***inc2*** works because you are directly calling it when you click the button, so the count2 value gets evaluated at that moment that you call it (therefore it will most probably have the current value).